# Recent inbox messages counts wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

As seen from the blue shading, I only had 2 new messages, but the red indicator showed 6. Such mismatch is very frequent. The blue shading is always right.

[image: 6 new or 2 new?]

Comment: Even though this has been answered, this question should've been posted on meta.SE instead.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thank you. I didn't even know there was such a thing as meta.SE.

Answer (score 5):

It's admittedly a bit confusing, but not really a bug.

If you get 10 comments on the same post, the inbox indicator will show **10** with a red background, but only a single thread will be displayed in your inbox. Likewise, several answers *to the same question* get gropued as well and will show up as a single item in the dropdown.

To keep track of unread answers and comments, you can navigate to the responses tab in your profile. ([direct link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m?tab=responses&sort=all)) Items with a yellowish background indicate new responses since the last time you visited the tab.

Comment: Really‽ So there is no 1:1 list of recent events I can use to make sure I've reacted (if necessary) to all of them?

Comment: There is, just on in your inbox, which only shows threads. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/adám?tab=responses&sort=all

Comment: Now, I don't understand. Look [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119472/be-the-first-1-leave-only-the-first-truthy?noredirect=1#comment292679_119472) that that thread did not have any other comments for a long time, and the last comment before the indicated one was mine, so none of the comments above should contribute to the count.

Comment: As I said, answers might collapse as well. Which is the answer in your inbox that shows below the two blue items? If it's MickyT's, you'd have 5 answers and 1 comments, which would account for 6 notifications.

Comment: Ah, I see. It were the answers that collapsed. There are new answers there that I never saw. Too bad. I like to read answers to my questions. Guess I have to read the activity log from now on. Thanks.

Comment: Can you migrate this question+answer to meta.SE?